# How can I send form values in jQuery submit without putting them in the form?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have multiple forms on a page all with the same fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="D">
```

Only the submit buttons and form actions are different for each. Is there a way to send this data in a JQuery submit so that I don't have to copy it 8 times for each form?

Comment: A querystring could potentially work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about appending them to the form when a given form is being submitted?

```
$("form").on("submit", function(){
   $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">')
   $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="2">')
   $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="D">')
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

You can add the values before the post occures

```
<form id="form1" onsubmit="add_values('form1');">
...
</form>
<form id="form1" onsubmit="add_values('form2');">
...
</form>

<script>
    function add_values(formid) {
        var input1 = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "cmd").val("_s-xclick");
        var input2 = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "p3").val("2");
        var input3 = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "t3").val("D");
        $('#'+formid).append($(input1));
        $('#'+formid).append($(input2));
        $('#'+formid).append($(input3));
        $('#'+formid).submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Recommending inline JavaScript for an application where jQuery is being used seems unnecessarily sloppy to me.  See answer by Chase for how to use jQuery.

Comment: TMHO, the question was about how not to repeat for several forms. Since no code was given as an example, I assumed the most trivial solution.